# How do I find the location on screen of a Rich Text Box selection?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to add a component at the location of every OLE in a Rich Text Box. I know how to retrieve the index of the selection, but is there a way to find the `Point` of the selection?
This is the code I am using:

```
        private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(FileTextBox.Rtf.Contains(@"\pict\wmetafile8\"))
        {
            var location = FileTextBox.SelectionStart.Text.IndexOf(@"\pict\wmetafile8\");
            //Here is where I want to place a new component at the location of the OLE
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the current x and y coordinates?

Comment: Well, you know how to get the index of the selection. If you read the documentation, you might have come across the method [`GetPositionFromCharIndex()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx)

Comment: Thank you peter! Exactly what I was looking for.